# Is white space legal in a connection string

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Is white space significant in a sql server or oracle connection string? eg are these two examples legal and equivalent, or not?

Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Northwind;server=(local)

Persist Security Info=False; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=Northwind ; server=(local)

The msdn documentation does not make this clear (to me).

TIA

Comment: Did you try them? Did they both work?

Comment: A test would not make it an authoritative answer.  And haughtonomous may not have both DBMS's available for testing.  Or different versions thereof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White space between the parts of a connection string is ignored.
Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240290(v=sql.105).aspx